# CQRS DDD - Commands and Domain Models relationship

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm practicing to implement a project using CQRS and DDD to the best I can and have come up with a question once building the commands.

**Scenario:** The user sends a command to create a bookshelf in the system which itself could also contain a collection of books.

The command looks like this:

```
public class CreateNewBookShelfCommand : ICommand
{
    public long CommandInitiatorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

All of the `Commands` reside in the `Contracts` project that itself is inside the `Application` solution folder.

The `Model` project residing in the `Domain` solution folder hosts the `BookShelf` entity class which includes a collection of Books.

**Questions 1:**  The command above has this `Books` property which is of type `Book`. My question is: should the `Commands` project directly reference the Model project so that the `Book` data type would be resolved in the `CreateNewBookShelfCommand`? Myself, I don't think that the `Contracts` are allowed to reference any project other than the `CommandHandlers` or anything else which might be *Cross Cutting*.

**Question 2:** So, is this a good practice to replicate part of the `Book` entity class here at the `Contracts` project and utilize it in the `CreateNewBookShelfCommand`?

And this is the Model project I have for `Book` and `BookShelf`:

```
public class BookShelf : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public BookShelfAccess Access { get; set; }

    public virtual BookShelfOwner Owner { get; set; }
    public long OwnerId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

 public class Book : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PublishedAt { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPublishes { get; set; }

    public virtual BookShelf Shelf { get; set; }
    public long ShelfId { get; set; }
}
```

I hope my explanation has been enough if there is any other information I should add here let me know.

Comment: `Book` what is? an Aggregate root? a nested entity? a value object? an ID?

Comment: Book is an Entity Class I have which resides in the Model project. And I'm not sure should reference the Model project from the Commands project or not. That's the question I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you would not use the entities in your domain model as elements of your command.

Commands are fundamentally *messages*, and as such they really ought to be immutable.  You want to know that what is received is the same thing that was sent.  In DDD terms, you might think of the messages as being *value objects*.

It doen't make sense to use an entity from your domain model as part of the in memory representation of your command, because you should never be invoking any of the entity methods that change its state.

Commands are much closer in nature to data transfer objects than they are to domain model entities.

Normally, all of the entity objects in your system should live behind an aggregate root interface, and the arguments that you pass to that interface are *values*.  If the domain model needs an entity, it can create one from the values provided.

Comment: Quite helpful answer @VoiceOfUnreason thanks. So, when you say that Commands are actually messages which should be immutable then I suppose I should actually make them so in the code base, I mean, to remove the Setter from the properties and pass the values using the constructor?

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason Commands *are* DTO's and *are not* Value Objects in the DDD sense of the term :) Value Objects can have behavior.